# Why or when should I cast callable function parameters to an rvalue before invocation?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, higher-order-functions

So far, I have considered passing and invoking a callable as

```
template <class Fct, class... Args> void f(Fct&& g, Args&&... args)
{
    g(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

is the way to go. Now in [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2UmDvg5xv1U&feature=youtu.be) (at 34 min.) and in the [std::invoke](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) example implementation, I saw an equivalence of the above snippet that conditionally casts the callable to an rvalue reference before invoking it,

```
template <class Fct, class... Args> void f(Fct&& g, Args&&... args)
{
    std::forward<Fct>(g)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

I assume that this modification only affects closures, but I still don't understand why the second version is preferable: the cast only affects rvalue arguments and no state should be copied upon invocation, correct? I also checked whether [std::function::operator()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator()) is overloaded on `&` and `&&` to get a hint by a library alternative to the above snippets, but this is not the case.

Thanks in advance for hints and answers!

Comment: Even if `std::function` doesn't have overload `operator () &&`, user provided functor might have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point of perfect forwarding is to preserve the original information as much as possible.

`g(std::forward<Args>(args)...);` will drop the rvalue/lvalue information of the original function object, `g` will *always* be treated as lvalue.

This will cause observable effect, for example:

```
struct foo {
    void operator()(int) & {
        std::cout << "& called\n";
    }

    void operator()(int) && {
        std::cout << "&& called\n";
    }
};
```

`foo{}(1)` will invoke the second `operator()`. If you use your first approach without `std::forward`, `f(foo{}, 1)` will invoke the first `operator()`.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for explanation & example! For passing lambdas it makes no difference then, right?

Comment: @lubgr Yes, for lambda there is no difference.